# How to access a service inside TemplateRef which was provided in parent component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Recently I had a task where I needed to pass a `TemplateRef` to component, which provides some service, say SomeService. And inside that template I used a directive that injects service SomeService. I ended up with `NullInjectorError`.

So my question is how can I get service provided in component but not inside ViewContent.

Here is minimal representation of what I'm trying to do. Let's assume that all components and directives are declared in the same module.

root-component. All that's happening here is that I'm passing a template reference to the app-component and use the directive inside template.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'root-component',
    template: `
    <app-component [itemTemplate]="template"></app-component>

    <ng-template #template >
        <div testDirective>hello</div>
    </ng-template>
    `
})
export class RootComponent {
}
```

app-component. Here I provide SomeService

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: `
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate"></ng-container>
    `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [
        SomeService // <-- HERE IS THE SERVICE THAT I'M TRYING TO INJECT INTO DIRECTIVE
    ],
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input()
    itemTemplate: TemplateRef<unknown> | null = null;

    constructor(
    ) {

    }
}
```

testDirective

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirective {
    constructor(
        private _someService: SomeService // <-- THIS CAUSE AN NullInjectorError
    ) {
    }
}
```

There is no need to show the implementation of `SomeService` as it is just a regular service.

I apologize if something is not clear, this is my first question on StackOverflow

[**Stackblitz here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqbunr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Angular v14 solution

With Angular 14, you can pass `injector` to `ngTemplateOutlet` directive. And by that way, the `embeddedView` that is going to render inside `ng-container` will refer to the current component injector tree (and point to injected `SomeService` provider on the component level.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
      <ng-container 
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate"
        [ngTemplateOutletInjector]="injector">
      </ng-container>
  `,
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input()
  itemTemplate: TemplateRef<unknown> | null = null;

  constructor(
    public readonly injector: Injector
  ) {}
}
```

---

### Angular v13 or less

You have to make some changes in the way the template has been passed. Rather than passing `TemplateRef` as `Input` binding. Pass that `ng-template` as a Content Projection.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'root-component',
  template: `
  <app-component>
    <!--Pass template as content projection-->
    <ng-template #template>
      <div testDirective>hello</div>
    </ng-template>
  </app-component>
  `,
})
export class RootComponent {}
```

And then `AppComponent` can use `@ContentChild` to lookup for that transcluded view (ng-template) thing checking `#template` template variable. And that's it. `itemTemplate` will fill in as soon as `ContentChild` query retrieves the result. Boom

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  // VVVV change here to ContentChild
  @ContentChild('template')
  itemTemplate: TemplateRef<unknown>;
}
```

In this case, the template is a part of `AppComponent`, and the injector tree resolves the `SomeService` correctly.

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ia2cpq)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about this new feature in Angular 14. Can I ask you where can I find changelog and new features for angular 14? Tried to look for it on official website but didn't find anything except for standalone components and other big improvements

Comment: [Angular v14 is now available](https://link.medium.com/0jbQTjWNxsb) or [Angular14 features slides](https://slides.com/pankajparkar/whats-new-in-angular-14)

Comment: @PankajParkar mindblowing slides!!!! awesome work!!!!